# Nougat: Possible to set all notifications from the Gmail app to not make any sound?:

Tags: notifications, gmail, 7.0-nougat

On Nougat is it possible to set all notifications from Gmail to not make any sound?

I want the notifications to appear just that they are not so urgent that they keep making sounds when they arrive. i.e. Immediate attention is not needed.

For Whatsapp it has internal settings where I've turned the sound off. But Gmail doesn't seem to offer such options so far as I can tell.

But is there an external way via Nougat to set what alerts / sounds a particular app's notifications will produce?

Comment: Don't know about Nougat but you could try with automation

Comment: You could try as in this [solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/171806/131553) - keep constraints blank

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the notification settings;

Settings -> account you want to make silent -> uncheck notifications or change preferences with the box below